# Can you help me to solve this summation equation?

Tags: calculus, summation, expected-value

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A1rV.png)
This is one equation is the one I calculated, but I cannot simplify it :(. Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Two points of vocabulary in your title 1) It is not an "equation" because it has no equal sign ; use the term "expression" or "sum" instead  2) You don't have to "solve" it but to *attempt* to find a **closed-form formula"** (which may not exist !) for it.

Comment: [See this book](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/Downld.html)